# Homotopical algebra is not concrete

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-categories

There is this old result by Freyd that "homotopy is not concrete":

> Freyd, Peter. "[*Homotopy is not concrete.*](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/6/tr6abs.html)" The Steenrod Algebra and Its Applications: A Conference to Celebrate NE Steenrod's Sixtieth Birthday. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 1970.

In 2017 we say that

> - there is a [homotopical category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopical+category) $(\bf Top, \cal W)$, such that the [localization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/localization) ${\bf Top}\!\!\left[{\cal W}^{-1}\right]$ is not ($\bf Set$-)[concrete](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/concrete+category).

The key result here is the following lemma, called "Isbell condition":

For $f\in {\cal A}/A$ an object of the slice category, let $C(f,B)$ be the class of pairs $u,v : A \to B$ such that $uf=vf$ as morphisms $\text{src}(f) \to A \to B$.

Define an equivalence relation $\asymp$ on $({\cal A}/A)_0$ that says $f\asymp g$ iff $C(f,B)=C(g,B)$ for every $B\in\cal A$, and let $\textsf{S}({\cal A}/A)$ the quotient $\left({\cal A}/A\right)_{0,/\asymp}$.

> **Isbell condition**: $\cal A$ is concrete if and only if $\textsf{S}({\cal A}/A)$ is a set for every $A\in\cal A$.

If you follow the development of this, you find another, slightly older paper

> Freyd, Peter. "*On the concreteness of certain categories.*" Symposia Mathematica. Vol. 4. 1969.

that develops quite a bit this technology, and contains (Thm 4.1) a result that in 2017 we write as

> - the localization ${\bf Cat}\!\!\left[\text{Eqv}^{-1}\right]$ of the category of categories to equivalences (i.e. the homotopy category [$\textsf{Ho}({\bf Cat}_\text{folk})$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/canonical+model+structure+on+Cat) is not concrete.

Now, following [Christie's meta-theorem](http://community.agathachristie.com/discussion/706/which-novel-quote) it's easy to wonder if there is a pattern, and maybe a proof, here.

Freyd's theorem is as old as Quillen's definition of a model category, so I doubt that Freyd ignored that you can ask the following question:

> - Let $\mho$ be a universe. If $\cal M \in {\bf Cat}$ is locally $\mho$-small and has a model structure, how often is the localization $\textsf{Ho}(\cal M)$ a ($\mho\text{-}\bf Set$-)concrete category?

(One could argue that this result really belongs to the world of homotopical categories and should be stated therein: it should, but a model structure is highly tamer to handle).

So:

- Has anybody attacked this problem with modern technology?
- Do you think that the above is a valuable question?
- I believe it is, because

  1. Every category that breaks Isbell condition (let's call it a "non-Isbell category" for the sake of brevity) seems quite nasty. And yet its homotopy theory can be well-understood. Isbell condition itself is stated in terms of the set theory of $\cal A$ and it is (unsurprisingly) linked to $\cal A$ having "nice" factorization systems ("nice" here means [proper](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/orthogonal+factorization+system)+something; did somebody explicitly prove this, maybe even Freyd?). So one can "foresee" if $\cal M$ will have a non-concrete localization proving that there is no homotopy-nice factorization system on $\cal M$ (a factorization system on $\cal M$ is homotopy-nice if it is an [homotopy FS](http://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/Bousfield_Fact.pdf) in the sense of Bousfield, and the FS induced by it on $\textsf{Ho}(\cal M)$ is nice).
  2. All these categories seem to exist (but I will be happy to see you disproving me, especially in the nontrivial cases):

     - a concrete category whose localization is concrete
     - a non-concrete category whose localization is concrete
     - a non-concrete category whose localization is non-concrete
     - a concrete category $\cal M$ whose allocalization ${\cal M}[\text{All}^{-1}]$ is non-concrete
     - a non-concrete category $\cal M$ whose allocalization ${\cal M}[\text{All}^{-1}]$ is concrete
     - a non-concrete category $\cal M$ whose allocalization ${\cal M}[\text{All}^{-1}]$ is non-concrete
     - a concrete category $\cal M$ whose allocalization ${\cal M}[\text{All}^{-1}]$ is non-concrete
  3. There's an interesting problem: every category is a quotient of a concrete category (Kučera, JPAA 1971, [link](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049%2871%2990004-1)). Is every category a *localization* of a concrete one?
- If $\textsf{Ho}(\cal M)$ is not concrete, there should be a property $P$ of $\cal M$ preventing $\textsf{Ho}(\cal M)$ to be Isbell. It seems obvious that every category $\cal N$ which is Quillen equivalent to $\cal M$ has $P$, and yet Freyd's technology seems to be rather context-specific, to the point that it's hard to believe that $P$ can be transported along the adjunction of a Quillen equivalence. Or maybe it is, under suitable assumptions?

Comment: Silly observation: In the first and third bullets of 2., you'd need some sort of non-triviality condition. And ditto for some of the others, else you can localise at the isomorphisms.

Comment: Also: I changed your SD direct link into a doi link, since that is more permanent.

Comment: I think a nice source of examples of "concrete homotopical algebra" comes from the hearts of $t$-structures on triangulated categories. I'm not sure, (someone please correct me if this is wrong!) but I suspect that if $C$ is a stable combinatorial model category with a reasonable $t$-structure, then the heart of the $t$-structure ought to be the homotopy category of another combinatorial stable model category, while at the same time being a locally presentable category, and thus concrete. There are also trivial examples, e.g. $(L,C,R)$ for a wfs $(L,R)$ on $C$ (so $ho(C)$ is trivial).

Comment: Funny, I never tought about this. This is related to the fact that the heart of the $t$-structure is abelian, and hence equivalent to its $(\infty,1)$-category (in whatever model), right? I'm more comfortable seeing a $t$-structure as a factorization system, on stable quasicategories, as you may remember; so let's state what you said in different terms (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) let $\cal C$ be a stable presentable quasicategory; and $t=({\cal C}^\ge, {\cal C}^<)$ a $t$-structure. Now (HA 1.3.5.23) the heart ${\cal C}^\heartsuit$ is presentable abelian and then "concrete" (but what's a "concrete" $(\infty,1)$-category???), and moreover equivalent to its "fundamental" category $ho({\cal C})$. That's truly inspiring (afaict, this answers a slightly different question)

Comment: I'd like to have a reference for the same result in stable model categories (how comes that the heart ${\cal C}^\heartsuit$ is equivalent to $ho({\cal C}')$?); also, what's a $t$-structure on a stable model category, precisely? I would say it's a a [normal torsion theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.7003) in the sense of Bousfield's homotopy factorization systems, but I remember it is still a [non well-understood question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/225954/reference-for-t-structures-on-stable-model-categories?rq=1) how to define them properly.

Comment: I guess I'm naively expecting that if $C$ is a model category presenting a stable $\infty$-category $C_\infty$ with a $t$-structure, then the full subcategory $C^0$ on objects of degree 0 should be a model category presenting the heart $C^\heartsuit = C^0_\infty$ of the $t$-structure on $C_\infty$. I guess I'm assuming that this will in particular mean that that the homotopy category of $C^0$ is exactly $C^\heartsuit$. And the point is that $C^\heartsuit$, though constructed as an $\infty$-category, is in fact an ordinary category, and it is concrete in the usual sense.

Comment: Possibly relevant for context and motivation: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21667/are-there-any-homotopical-spaces  and  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/190578/can-one-make-a-category-concrete-by-enlarging-the-universe

Comment: That is properly where the question have been motivated.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but I was under the impression that each category was isomorphic to its ‘Cayley representation’ which is itself a concrete category.  How does this fail for the examples above? Is $S({\bf Ho}(\mathcal{M}),A)$ a proper class for some $A$?

Comment: I can't deduce what you mean by 'Cayley representation' from your notation, so please explain. In case you mean the Yoneda embedding, keep in mind that the category of functors $[A,B]$ between two large categories is not legitimate because each hom-class is proper.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, the system never pinged me - by the Cayley representation of $\mathcal{C}$ I had in mind the category whose objects are the Hom-sets of $\mathcal{C}$ and whose arrows are the functions induced by composition in Hom-sets, but the Yoneda embedding should also suffice -- the question I posed at the end was a non-sequitur wondering how exactly the Isbell condition fails. The legitimacy of these constructions seems to depend on which set theoretical universe we work in, in Ackermann set theory or $MK+CC$ they're legitimate -- see https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.1279.pdf p.25-26.

Comment: More generally I wonder if the non-concreteness of these categories is a result of working in a set theoretical universe that is 'too weak' like $ZFC$, in the sense that they can be made 'class concrete' in a stronger background universe, or if something more subtle is going on here.

Answer (score 10):

This stream of thought led to the following preprint that has been on the arXiv for a few days. https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00303

This is not an act of self-promotion, but maybe some of the interested readers of this thread can find some development of these ideas.

Comments are welcome, and in fact encouraged.